# output text to top rather than bottom

Tags: javascript

I have written a function to submit text into a container . the text gets added to the bottom of each block of text; I would like it to be added to the top of the previous text block rather than bottom.

Here is my code:

```
function submit() {


var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
var y = document.getElementById("input").value;
var z = document.getDate;
if(x.length == 0 || y.length == 0 ){

    alert('please enter valid information');
    return false;
}


document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += Date() + "</br>" + "   </br>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += y + "</br>" + "</br>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += x + "</br>" + "</br>"; 
document.getElementById("text").value = "";
document.getElementById("input").value = "";

 return true;                     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reasign the innerhtml after the added content, like this:

```
function submit() {


var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
var y = document.getElementById("input").value;
var z = document.getDate;

if(x.length == 0 || y.length == 0 ){

    alert('please enter valid information');
    return false;
}


document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = Date() + "</br></br>" + y +       
    "</br></br>"+ x +"</br></br>" +document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("text").value = "";
document.getElementById("input").value = "";



return true;                     
}
```

Thats assuming you are not using Jquery, otherwhise just use `.prepend()`

Comment: @sosro: Mark this answer as correct answer. As, the user has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The `variable += "text"` statement is shorthand for `variable = variable + "text"` Thus, it will concatenate the text you provide it after the text already in the variable. In this case, the variable is the `innerHTML` property of the container. So the text is being concatenated to the end of the text already in the container.

But you want the new text concatenated *before* the existing text. So you'll have to read the existing text out of the container, then concatenate it to the end of the new text, something like this: `variable = "text" + variable`.

You might think you could do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = Date() + "</br>" + "   </br>" + document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = y + "</br>" + "</br>" + document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x + "</br>" + "</br>" + document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
```

But you'll find that that doesn't do what you want either, as it will make the container contents be in reverse order. That, of course, happens because the `innerHTML` in each step includes the results of the previous step. This leaves two options: either add all the text in one lump, or add it to a string separately and then prepend that to the contents of the container. An example of the latter:

```
var new_data = Date() + "</br>" + "   </br>";
new_data = new_data + y + "</br>" + "</br>";
new_data = new_data + x + "</br>" + "</br>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = new_data + document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
```

Of course, since the second and third lines of the snippet above are appending the values `y + "</br>" + "</br>"` and `x + "</br>" + "</br>"` to the end of `new_data`, the code could be written as

```
var new_data = Date() + "</br>" + "   </br>";
new_data += y + "</br>" + "</br>";
new_data += x + "</br>" + "</br>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = new_data + document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
```

Notice the use of `+=` to do the appending!